# how to show all gtest case by bazel without "test" cmd

Tags: bazel

I want to query all gtest cases by bazel,

parameter "--gtest_filter"  only can be used with "bazel test " cmd

and I am try to use "bazel query bazel query //xxx:all", but it will show the test list which defined in BUILD file , I want to get the cases list from  xxx.cc files.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a job that `bazel query` can do. Query operates on the graph structure of targets. A fundamental design decision of Bazel is that this graph can be computed by looking only at `BUILD` files and the `.bzl` files they depend on. In particular, parsing source files is not allowed.

(The argument to `--test_filter` is simply passed through the test runner; Bazel does not know what it represents.)

Answer (score 0):

If you use CLion with the Bazel plugin you get the following view for googletest tests:

[image]

This works even with Catch2 (but for Catch2 the view is not so nice). I guess that's some IDE magic here - nevertheless, it gives you what you want. I assume you can also come up with some type of [Bazel Aspect](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/aspects.html) that produces this information for you.

I tested this also with Lavender (with minor modifications) and Visual Studio which gives me in the test overview also a list of all test:

[image]